# Why does 'vertical-align: middle' work for OpenPyXL, but not for XlsxWriter engine in to_excel() when applied as style?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I couldn't find a matching issue on the [pandas GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) regarding my problem, and before opening one, I just wanted to make sure, that I don't miss any (obvious) mistake on my side. Most of the Q&As here and elsewhere focus on headers, and the specific problems within that scope.

So, basically I want to use [pandas styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html), and specifically [export to Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel). As to the linked documentation, `vertical-align` is supported, and according to [this test for the `to_excel()` function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/io/formats/test_to_excel.py), the correct usage for centred vertical alignment is `'vertical-align: middle'`.

If I use the OpenPyXL engine in `to_excel()`, that actually works pretty well, see the following (not so minimal) example:

```py
import pandas as pd

def align(data):
    return pd.DataFrame('text-align: center', index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

def valign(data):
    return pd.DataFrame('vertical-align: middle', index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

def whitespace(data):
    return pd.DataFrame('white-space: normal', index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

d = {'col1': ['first\nsecond', 'only one'], 'col2': ['only one', 'first\nsecond']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.style.apply(align, axis=None).apply(valign, axis=None).apply(whitespace, axis=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test sheet')
```

I apply three different styles:

- centred horizontal alignment; just as a general test, that the styling works
- centred vertical alignment; as described above
- `'whitespace: normal'`; as this is necessary to have proper "expanded" cells in Excel along with the centred vertical alignment (please see the below images to understand, what I mean)

The output for the OpenPyXL engine, as stated, is fine:

[image: OpenPyXL]

Now, let's switch the engine to XlsxWriter:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test sheet')
```

The result is the following:

[image: XlsxWriter]

As you can see, the vertical alignment is set to bottom. Nevertheless, the horizontal alignment as well as the whitespace/wrapping is correctly set. Also, `'vertical-align: top'` works as expected. It seems, that specifically `'vertical-align: middle'` doesn't work properly with the XlsxWriter engine.

**Is there anything I can further test – or is this just a plain bug in pandas?**

Some further remarks:

- The OpenPyXL engine works, of course. But, I would like to use the XlsxWriter engine, since the post-processing – from my point of view – becomes easier.
- I could manually generate the whole Excel document with XlsxWriter, that's true. But, the usage/maintainance of the final code must be as easy as possible, since co-workers using this code aren't expected to be Python/pandas experts.
- If that's an actual bug, it should be fixed nonetheless. :-)

---

**EDIT:** I should've mentioned that in the first place; so here's an answer to [Hans' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208392/why-does-vertical-align-middle-work-for-openpyxl-but-not-for-xlsxwriter-engi?noredirect=1#comment104635750_59208392): I can explicitly generate the correct output solely using the XlsxWriter engine, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['first\nsecond', 'only one'], 'col2': ['only one', 'first\nsecond']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test sheet')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Test sheet']
    fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter', 'text_wrap': True})
    worksheet.set_column('B:C', None, fmt)
```

Notice: There's no `df.style.apply`!

The problem here is, I specifically need another, non-trivial pandas style which changes the background color with respect to some constraints, which can't be attacked with (XlsxWriter's) [conditional formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) – or at least as not as easy as with the pandas style. Therefore, all cells already have a style, which then can't be overriden later, cf. the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def whitespace(data):
    return pd.DataFrame('white-space: normal', index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

d = {'col1': ['first\nsecond', 'only one'], 'col2': ['only one', 'first\nsecond']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.style.apply(whitespace, axis=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test sheet')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Test sheet']
    fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})
    worksheet.set_column('B:C', None, fmt)
```

[image: This doesn't work.]

As you can see, the wrapping from the pandas style is applied, whereas the horizontal and vertical alignments from the XlsxWriter formatting are ignored.

Comment: According to https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_align, XlsxWriter uses `vcenter` instead of `middle`. Depending on whether Pandas does any verification itself before passing those arguments to the writer, using `vcenter` in your `valign` might be a workaround. At the same time, if that works, I think it would be an indication that Pandas is not mapping the attribute value for XlsxWriter.

Comment: @Hans I edited my question to elaborate on this, please have a look. After working on that issue for several hours now, I'm in fact quite sure, that the mapping you mention is broken in pandas. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the right section in the pandas source code by now. If anybody could give a hint, where to look, I would continue digging through the pandas source code on my own - to have a "proof" for the bug and to open the mentioned issue on their GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py seems to define style mappings, but it would seem to me your example is fleshed out enough as it is to serve as a bug submission.

Comment: @Hans From your hint, I could find one or two (more) evidences for my assumption, and now opened an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30107). I will leave this question open, if somebody can add more information.

Comment: Please don't tag this with OpenPYXL as it doesn't seem to apply: you are trying to solve a problem with xlswriter.